# How do I count true values returned by array iteration with condition?

Tags: ruby, arrays, boolean, iteration

I have:

```
def distance(str1, str2)
  str1.chars.each_index do |index| 
    difference?(str1, str2, index)
  end
end

def difference?(str1, str2, index)
  if !str1.chars[index].nil? && !str2.chars[index].nil?
    str1.chars[index] != str2.chars[index]
  end
end
```

For each element in `str1.chars`, which are different from elements in `str2.chars` with the same `index`, `difference?` returns `true`.

How can I count how many times it returned `true` in `distance`?

I used something like this:

```
def distance(str1, str2)
  distance = 0
  str1.chars.each_index do |index| 
    if  difference?(str1, str2, index)
      distance += 1
    end
  end
  distance
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe `count` with a block is the answer, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def distance(str1, str2)
  str1.each_char.with_index.count do |_, index| 
    difference?(str1, str2, index)
  end
end

distance("foo", "bar") # => 3
distance("foo", "foobar") # => 0
distance("foobar", "foo") # => 0
```

Comment: I like this solution, but can you explain why there is `_` inside `|_, index|`?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). There's a gem for that:

```
require 'levenshtein'
Levenshtein.distance("abc","abd") #=> 1
```

The gem is likely to be faster than other solutions because it uses native extensions.